# If moksha is true then will prahlad take rebirth in next cycle of four yug for narsingh avtar of shri hari?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, bhagavad-gita

See if we look at character of prahlad we will find that they would have attained moksha. But if yes then will narsingh avtar not take place in next four yug cycle. aatma is amar and its supreme destination is moksha but if these aatma attained moksha. What about avtar of narsingh in next satyug?
In bhagvad gita it's written no rebirth after moksha so is moksha only for 1 cycle of four yug Or for forever

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://rockmine.blogspot.com/2023/10/stackexchange-if-moksha-is-true-then.html here are my thoughts on the same. my answer got delted by moderator littlenaruto for not providing source, I cannot provide sources for how I understand them.

Comment: Bro what's source that moksha is for one kalpa. I think it's for forever in gita also. It says the same

Answer (score 1):

[This Chapter 1.5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115940.html) of Sri Vishnu Purana says the following.:

Summary.:

> More particular account of creation. Origin of different orders of beings from Brahmā's body under different conditions; and of the Vedas from his mouths. **All things created again as they existed in a former Kalpa.**

It further says.:

> Parāśara said:—
>
> Created beings, although they are destroyed (in their individual forms) at the periods of dissolution, **yet, being affected by the good or evil acts of former existence, they are never exempted from their consequences;** and when Brahmā creates the world anew, they are the progeny of his will, in the fourfold condition of gods, men, animals, or inanimate things.
>
> .
>
> **In like manner as the products of the seasons designate in periodical revolution the return of the same season, so do the same circumstances indicate the recurrence of the same Yuga, or age; and thus, in the beginning of each Kalpa, does Brahmā repeatedly create the world, possessing the power that is derived from the will to create,** and assisted by the natural and essential faculty of the object to be created.

Each Puranas, states the stories of different different kalpas.

Chapter 53 of Matsya Purana mentions Kalpas of all Puranas except Brahma and Markandeya Puranas.:

> Padma Purana - Padma Kalpa (hence the name)
>
> Vishnu Purana - Varaha Kalpa (current Kalpa)
>
> Vayu Purana (includes Shiva Purana) - Sveta Kalpa
>
> Bhagavata Purana - Sarsvata Kalpa
>
> Naradiya Purana - Brhat Kalpa
>
> Agni Purana - Isana Kalpa
>
> Bhavishya Purana - Aghora Kalpa
>
> Brahma Vaivarata Purana - Rathantara Kalpa
>
> Linga Purana - Agneya Kalpa
>
> Varaha Purana - Manava Kalpa
>
> Skanda Purana - Satpurusha Kalpa
>
> Vamana Purana - Kurma Kalpa
>
> Kurma Purana - Lakshmi Kalpa
>
> Matsya Purana - Vaivastara Manvantara of Varaha Kalpa
>
> Brahmanda Purana - Future Kalpas (No specific name mentioned)*

Plus, there are multi-universal or multi-versal concept.

Sri Shiva Gita 7:13-22.:

> Suta said.: In this way spoke lord Shiva and blessed Rama with divine eyes. Thereafter lord Shiva showed Rama by opened his mouth which was as wide as Patala loka. Blazing with billions of lightening strikes seeing such a dreadful scene Sri Rama trembling with fear collapsed on the ground on his knees. He prostrated on the ground and numerous times he prayed to Lord Shiva. Then that mighty armed hero Rama gaining some strength again looked at the cosmic form of the Eswara the destroyer of the three cities. **He sighted billions of universes as like as the groundnuts being roasted in blazing fires.** He saw inside the mouth Meru, Mandara Vindhya etc. giant mountains, seven great oceans, Sun, moon and planets, five elements, all deities, all dense forests. He also witnessed the mighty serpent Adi-Sesha, fourteen worlds, **in every universes he witnessed** Devasura Sangrama (battles of gods and demons), their cause and effects. **He also witnessed Lord Vishnu's ten primary incarnations and their roles, duties and works.** He witnessed God's valor, the event of destruction of the three cities by Shiva. He saw all the creatures who are yet to be born, which were born in past and which were being born. He further saw the destruction of all these creation. Seeing that horrifying scene, Sri Rama despite being a wise man, trembled with fear and saluted Lord Shiva again and again. Then Rama sang the essence of all Upanishads as a hymn in praise of Lord Shiva.

So, basically, in each kalpas everyone repeats their same cycle with slight differences due to Kalpa-bheda.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Means even if I get moksha  again I have to come back, then what's point of moksha? What's point of practicing karmyog

Comment: There can also be another possibility, that every other jeeva is also a post n if anyone gets moksha they will get replace by other jiva as an image of the previous jeeva as Yoga Visishta says that there are infinite tridevs, etc n also in other universes also n so on. So, a possibility that from a blade of grass to the tridevas all are post and are under Nirguna Brahman. Just, a speculation.